# Javascript "clearInterval" method cannot stop the timer when defined outside of window.onload

Tags: javascript

I declared a function containing setInterval and a function containing clearInterval outside of window.onload = function(){...} . However the timer cannot be stopped as expected

When I clicked the start button, I can see the timer start correctly and "hello" is being printed in the consoled repetitively. However, when I clicked the "stop" button, the timer won't be cleared.

I think upon loading of the document, the onclick function for "start_btn" and "stop_btn" should be ready, then I use the start button and it will set the variable "timer" to a number, and later I click the stop button, why it cannot see the current non-null "timer" variable?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
      *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function(){
        var timer = null;
        var start_btn = document.getElementById("start");
        var stop_btn = document.getElementById("stop");

        startFunc(start_btn, timer);
        stopFunc(stop_btn, timer);

      };

      function startFunc(target, timer){
        target.onclick = function(){
          timer = setInterval(function(){
            console.log("hello");
          }, 300);
        };
      }

      function stopFunc(target, timer){
        target.onclick = function(){
          clearInterval(timer);
        };
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="start">start</button>
    <button type="button" id="stop">stop</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `startFunc` is only modifying the local copy of `timer`. Consider widening its scope or passing around an object so that it can be mutated when passed as an argument.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like CollinD said in comment the problem is the scope of `timer`, you can get the thing to work by making `timer` part of th outside scope

```js
var timer = null;
window.onload = function(){
  var start_btn = document.getElementById("start");
  var stop_btn = document.getElementById("stop");

  startFunc(start_btn);
  stopFunc(stop_btn);

};

function startFunc(target){
  target.onclick = function(){
    timer = setInterval(function(){
      console.log("hello");
    }, 300);
  };
}

function stopFunc(target){
  target.onclick = function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
      *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="start">start</button>
    <button type="button" id="stop">stop</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The reason being `setInterval` return an `int` being the ID of the interval and not an object so what's send is a copy of the variable and not the variable itself

---

if you don't want it to be part of the outside scope then you need to send it has an `object` like that since they are sent themselves and not by copy :

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var timer = {a: null}
  var start_btn = document.getElementById("start");
  var stop_btn = document.getElementById("stop");

  startFunc(start_btn, timer);
  stopFunc(stop_btn, timer);

};

function startFunc(target, timer){
  target.onclick = function(){
    timer.a = setInterval(function(){
      console.log("hello");
    }, 300);
  };
}

function stopFunc(target, timer){
  target.onclick = function(){
    clearInterval(timer.a);
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
      *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="start">start</button>
    <button type="button" id="stop">stop</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So does it mean in the stack frame for startFunc, there's a variable "timer", and in stack frame stopFunc, there's another variable "timer", and they are different variables? Why this works when variable timer is an object, but not working when timer is a primitive type? Is it because of the heap memory?

Comment: @Mr.Snail it is because, like I said primitive types are send as a copy of themselves, while object are send themselves. That's how most of the languages I know works, I think it is because copying some object may be a bad idea, like you said for heap memory, but to be honest I don't know the in depth reason.

Comment: Okay this makes me much clearer now. Thank you so much for your codes!

Comment: @Mr.Snail also JavaScript as a specificity allowing you to add property to a primitive (`let x = 1; x.a = 42;`) but in the case the value sent to function is the primitive 1 and the 42 is lost